# a Cauchy sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

I have to proof that a Cauchy sequence converges.

For a Caughy sequence it is true that
$$\forall  \varepsilon >0  \exists \nu : \forall n, m> \nu   , |a_m-a_n|< \varepsilon $$.

We can put $\varepsilon =1$ and then:

$$  \exists \nu : \forall n, m> \nu   , |a_m-a_n|< 1 $$.

In particular, we can put $m=\nu+1$. And then for $n> \nu$ we have:

$$|a_n-a_{\nu+1}| \ge |a_n|-|a_{\nu+1}|  \Longrightarrow |a_n| \le|a_{\nu+1}|+|a_n-a_{\nu+1}| \ge |a_{\nu+1}|+ 1 $$

**At this point I can't understand why it says that:
$$|a_n|<|a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_{\nu}|$$**

and then it follows that (and it is clear to me why):
$$|a_n|<|a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_{\nu}|+|a_{\nu+1}|+ 1 =M$$
and $a_n$ is limitated.

Comment: Not all Cauchy sequences converge. From a quick scan it looks like you want to prove that every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ converges. You may not know it yet, but that extra bit is very important!

Comment: @dbx Yes, indeed. I want to prove that every C. sequence in R converge but this limit can also be infinite

Comment: Need more information: Cauchy sequences in what space? If you are talking about the real numbers, then the proof would very much depend on your definition of the real.

Comment: "every C. sequence in R converge but this limit can also be infinite" Sorry but what are you talking about? Real valued Cauchy sequences could be unbounded, you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were trying to prove was that every Cauchy sequence is bounded. In fact, you have reached the inequality $|a_n|\le|a_{v+1}|+|a_n-a_{v+1}|\le|a_{v+1}|+1$ for all $n\gt v$. Also, for all $a_i$ with $1\le i \le v$ we have $|a_i| \le |a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_v|$. Hence,combining these two relations we have $|a_i|\le|a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_v|+|a_{v+1}|+1$ for all $i$ , showing that this sequence is bounded. Now try to prove that {$a_n$} converges using the least upper bound property of the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me whether you are reading a proof and can't understand it, or are stuck with a step in the proof. My immediate thought is that it's not so simple to prove, just by knowing a Cauchy sequence is bounded as suggested by another comment.

Here is a suggestion. You know that $\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property (which also implies the greatest lower bound property).

Then it is easy to prove if $(a_n)$ is a bounded above *weakly increasing* sequence, i.e. $a_{i+1}\geq a_i$, then it converges to the least upper bound of the set $X=\{a_1, a_2, ...\}$.

The problem is that a cauchy sequence might not be weakly increasing, for points may oscillate back and forth. But we can find a way to ignore the oscillations as follows.

Next  given a cauchy sequence $(a_i)$, it is bounded (both above and below).  Define a new squence $(b_i)$ where $b_i=\inf\{a_i,a_{i+1},...\}$ where $\inf$ is the greatest lower bound. Argue that $(b_i)$ is a weakly increasing sequence, and that the limit is the limit of $(a_i)$.

The picture is this. Imagine the points $a_i$ as oscillating back and forth. The point $b_j$ is the 'outer left edge' of the oscillation from time $j$ onwards. Since the sequence is cauchy, we expect the oscillations to eventually die down, and so the outer edge converges to a point.